# Guardar datos de archivo en ArrayList y desplegarlo de mayor a menor.

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

Estoy trabajando en un programa que obtenga datos de un archivo de texto, que obtenga solo los primeros 100 y tener un metodo que ordene del primero al ultimo o viceversa y otro que busque un nombre especifico en el archivo.
 Esto es lo que tengo por el momento.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;

public class distritos
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner entrada;
        File archivo;
        String a;
        String linea;
        ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();
        try
        {
            entrada = new Scanner("Texto.txt");
            a = entrada.nextLine();
            archivo = new File(a);
            entrada = new Scanner(archivo);

            int comienzo = 0;
            while(entrada.hasNextLine() && comienzo < 100)
            {

                linea = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println(linea);
                comienzo++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Lo probe y funciona bien, obtiene las primeras 100 lineas y las imprime, sin embargo, tengo problemas a la hora de ordernarlo y no se por donde empezar.

Comment: Recibes 100 números?

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la condición para ordenar?

Comment: Sería bueno que nos mostraras qué está contenido en el archivo

Comment: Son 100 lineas que contienen direcciones, la condicion para ordenar es simplemente de inicio a final o final a inicio, basicamente revertirlo. No inclui el archivo por que son muchas lineas y no estoy seguro de como ponerlo aqui sin arruinar la pregunta.

Comment: Cuando te hablo de criterio para ordenar me refería a si lo querías ordenar alfabéticamente o de otra manera

Comment: La mejor manera ordenar un Array de tipos primitivos es con la clase Collections.sort y Collections.reverseOrder

Comment: @Eleber de acuerdo a tu código, puedes agregar los valores en un ArrayList y posteriormente ordenarlos usando Collections.sort(lista);, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Antes de imprimir las lineas, tienes que ordenarlas, para esto puedes usar un `ArrayList` e introducir los valores de cada linea que contiene el archivo

```
    ...
    ...
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    int comienzo = 0;
     while(entrada.hasNextLine() && comienzo < 100)
     {

         linea = entrada.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(linea);
         lista.add(linea); //Agrega valor a ArrayList
         comienzo++;
     }
     ...
     ...
```

Posteriormente puedes usar para ordenar alfabéticamente el arraylist **[Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))** y posteriormente imprimir los valores ordenados, de esta forma:

```
        Collections.sort(lista);
        //Ahora imprime valores ordenados
        for(String valor: lista){
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
```

De acuerdo a el código de tu pregunta, esta sería la forma de realizarlo:

```
    Scanner entrada;
    File archivo;
    String a;
    String linea;
   // ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        entrada = new Scanner("Texto.txt");
        a = entrada.nextLine();
        archivo = new File(a);
        entrada = new Scanner(archivo);

        int comienzo = 0;
        while(entrada.hasNextLine() && comienzo < 100)
        {

            linea = entrada.nextLine();
           // System.out.println(linea);
            lista.add(linea); //Agrega valor a ArrayList
            comienzo++;
        }

        //Despues de agregar a ArrayList, ordena.
        Collections.sort(lista);
        //Ahora imprime los valores ordenados.
        for(String valor: lista){
            System.out.println(valor);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.